# Javascript function to find email address from a webpage

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to write a javascript function to read all the email addresses and make it to link.
for example if it finds `test@example.com` replace it with `<a href="mailto:test@example.com">test@example.com</a>`.

I am using this:

```
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/([a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+)/gi, <a href="mailto:$1">$1</a>'));
```

It work fine for simple email addresses.

But the problem is if the email address already in this format:

```
"<a href="mailto:test@example.com">test@example.com</a>"
```

Then It does not work. The output becomes wrong like this:

```
test@example.com">test@example.com
```

Please suggestive me any solution. So the function can work fine.

Or any other function to make the simple email a link and if the email is already in mailto: link form then do nothing.

Comment: That's why you should not apply the expression on the raw HTML string, but recursively iterate over all DOM nodes and only apply the expression to text nodes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one method which only makes the replacement if a character before the email is not `>`, `:`, `"` or `'`. It is basically a way of emulating a negative look-behind

```
var str = ' test@example.com <a href="mailto:test@example.com">test@example.com</a> ',
    rex = /(["'>:]?)([\w.-]+@[\w.-]+\.[\w.-]+)/gi;

str = str.replace( rex, function ( $0, $1 ) {
    return $1 ? $0 : '<a href="mailto:' + $0 + '">' + $0 + '</a>';
});

// " <a href="mailto:test@example.com">test@example.com</a> <a href="mailto:test@example.com">test@example.com</a> "
```

`\w` is equivalent to `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`.

To be more particular about when a replacement is to be prevented you could change `rex` above to something like

```
rex = /(<a href(?:(?!<\/a\s*>).)*)?([\w.-]+@[\w.-]+\.[\w.-]+)/gi;
```

This would only prevent a replacement if the email appeared between `<a href` and `</a>`.

None of these sort of regex solutions are watertight, but in some circumstances they may be good enough.